# シェルコンテキストメニューに 7zip を登録できない

Tags: windows

Scoop 経由でインストールしたものとなります。
右クリックメニューでできたほうが楽なので、出したいのですが何故かできず。
Scoopで管理するのが楽なため解決したいのですが、いい方法はないでしょうか。

環境は Windows 11 Home (64bit) です。Windows 10でも同様の問題が発生します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: @raccy バージョン依存する話題でもないですし、win11タグを指定する意味はないと思うんですが。

Comment: @sayuri 元々windows-10がついていたので、windows-11のタグがないから消してしまったのかと思いました。質問からはWindows11固有の問題なのか、Windows共通の問題なのかは判断できないので、一応付けておいた方がいいかなと思っています。

Comment: すみません、質問者です。申し訳ないのですが最初タグ登録する際にwindows11が見つからずwindows10でも同様の問題が発生していましたので暫定的に10タグをつけてしまいました。11のタグを登録してくださりありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「シェルコンテキストメニューに7-Zipを登録」を変更する場合は、7-Zip File Managerを「管理者として実行」する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます
解決できました!